# Comando read se perde ao usar as setas no MingW

Tags: bash

Estou precisando ler uma informação da linha de comando. Aqui no trabalho usamos o MingW que vem embarcado no SourceTree.

Para tal necessidade, tentei usar a função *built-in* da [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) `read`, porém ela não se comporta muito bem se eu precisar corrigir o texto digitado usando as setas.

Por exemplo, se eu quiser digitar `add`, mas sem querer digitei `asd`. Eu navego uma casa para o lado <kbd><=</kbd>, dou um <kbd>backspace</kbd> e então digito <kbd>d</kbd>. Quando mando exibir a variável, em compensação... fica uma confusão. Veja no gif:

[image: confusão ao ler a variável]

Eu também redirecionei para um arquivo e obtive isso ao abrir com o VIM:

[image: arquivo aberto pelo VIM]

Então, como posso ler da linha de comando sem ter esse comportamento imprevisto ao usar as setas?

Answer (score -2):

Em vez de armazenar em uma variavel, siga sua segunda ideia utilizando um log ou um arquivo de texto.

```
    inn(){
    read LINE | tee -a log_LINE
    }
    cat log_LINE >> /dev/null
    echo "$?"
    echo "deseja inserir a linha novamente? (S/N)"
    read XXX
    if [ XXX == s ]; then
    rm log_LINE 
    inn;
    elif [ XXX == n ]; then
    echo "nao selecionado"
    fi
```

o inn é um uma palavra generica, pode se usar qualquer uma com a estrutura abaixo:
palavra() {conteudo}

sempre que utilizar "palavra;" o codigo ira retormar o conteudo que está dentro das chaves.
utilizar o tee -a em vez de >> para que você consiga visualizar a saida do comando.